# Как убрать лишнее до и после символов кодирования в массиве с картинкой в base64

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, base64, photo

Есть вот такая конструкция, содержащая картинку в base 64.

`[{"type":"image/jpeg","id":"uppy-refugee/jpg-1e-image/jpeg-103345-1674929741615","data":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7QA6UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAB4cAlAACHJhbnBsZXR0HAJuAAxHZXR0eSBJbWFn...671zne4YcbDme7M1JuD/VcEBLG9K7pT/EwvC3O39za7T6bfRTYy0z//2Q==","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"refugee.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"name":"refugee.jpg","size":103345,"dataFormat":"Base64"}]`

Мне нужно убрать все лишнее:
Все что расположено до `"data:image` и после `","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"refugee.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"name":"refugee.jpg","size":103345,"dataFormat":"Base64"}]`

Как это можно сделать? Возможно с помощью regexp replace, но мне сложно составить подобный запрос.

Comment: Эта конструкция уже в виде массива объектов представлена, или строкой?

Comment: судя по скобкам и парам ключ значение похожа на массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярные выражения тут лишнее.

У вас строка - это очень похоже на JSON. Возможно вы и получаете это как массив объектов, но потом "превращаете" это в строку.

Но предположим, что исходные данные, это строка.

Тогда

```js
var str = '[{"type":"image/jpeg","id":"uppy-refugee/jpg-1e-image/jpeg-103345-1674929741615","data":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7QA6UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAB4cAlAACHJhbnBsZXR0HAJuAAxHZXR0eSBJbWFn...671zne4YcbDme7M1JuD/VcEBLG9K7pT/EwvC3O39za7T6bfRTYy0z//2Q==","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"refugee.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"name":"refugee.jpg","size":103345,"dataFormat":"Base64"}]';
console.log(str);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);
var img = obj[0].data;
console.log(img);
```

В **obj** в результате получаем массив объектов. Правда там только один элемент.

А в **img** будет та строка, которая вам нужна.

Comment: большое Вам спасибо! Все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так достать эти данные:

```js
const arr = [{"type":"image/jpeg","id":"uppy-refugee/jpg-1e-image/jpeg-103345-1674929741615","data":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7QA6UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAB4cAlAACHJhbnBsZXR0HAJuAAxHZXR0eSBJbWFn...671zne4YcbDme7M1JuD/VcEBLG9K7pT/EwvC3O39za7T6bfRTYy0z//2Q==","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"refugee.jpg","type":"image/jpeg"},"name":"refugee.jpg","size":103345,"dataFormat":"Base64"}];

console.log(arr[0].data);
```